# Uploading image to google doc via google form

Tags: google-docs, google-forms

I'm creating a application form, where users input their info, and after submitting, the form "generates" a google doc with those information and sends that document to my email. That works fine.
My problem is this:
I also need users to upload their picture, and then I have to include that  picture inside of that google doc. Can you please help me solve this problem?

Comment: Google Forms doesn't have a file upload feature.  And you can't access the users local drive from Apps Script server side code, so if the user entered a file name, that wouldn't work either.  If their picture is in their Google Drive, and not their local (like hard drive), the user would need to give permission for your code to access their Google Drive.  Which isn't possible to do with the user of the Google Form.  If you developed an Apps Script Web App, then you can upload a file from the users local drive.  There are posts that deal with that.  Where is the file coming from?  Local drive?

Comment: Yes, they have to upload their picture from their hard drive.

Comment: Can't do it with a Google Form. It's a common issue. You will either need to use an Apps Script Web App, and create your own HTML input form, or use some other product.

Comment: Another alternative would be to create a an Add-on that people can install in a Google doc.  But you would still need to create all your own HTML and the input form and use a file picker input.

Comment: Thank you for your help.